# Size on disk vs size - data copied from Android

Tags: disk-drive

I need some help. I recently switched the ROM on my Android phone and copied all the data before hand from my phone's internal storage to my local HDD on my laptop. Successfully changed the ROM but when I tried to copy the data back, I found that I can't because the size is 1.47PB when the size on disk is 17.5GB. I've tried to compress it and to defrag it but that lead to nowhere

[image: Size vs Size on Disk]

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Could you please **[edit]** your question and include 1) where those data were copied from (e.g. internal SD card) and 2) how you performed the copy? I doubt your H: drive has the size indicated there, so this rather seems to be a Windows problem.

Comment: .. and also what exactly *“when I tried to copy the data back, **I found that I can't”*** means? What error did you get? There must be some sparse file with abnormal size. You need to find and delete that by looking at size of individual files.

Comment: First check your disk from an admin command line using `chkdsk H: /F` to eliminate the disk problem you have. Second you can still copy back the data folder by folder sorted by priority e.g. pictures first. If you don't know what the data is for just don't copy it.

Comment: Hey! The data was copied from my phone's internal storage to my local hard drive - CTRL C and CTRL V. No, the drive only has 1TB. I'm not quite sure if this is a Windows problem since the issue only resides on the files I've copied from my phone. When I tried to copy the data back, I received an error that I do not have enough storage to copy the selected files(due to the abnormal Size they have). Tried to run chkdsk H: /F and results are as following : https://gyazo.com/15571ac7576cf11cb8e7a675cd346d9e

Comment: Regarding the files that I'm trying to copy, for example I cannot copy my pictures back because each one of them is 66.1GB https://gyazo.com/80fa9774b2fed5d775a4599fe2a92f8c

Comment: Looks like something was running completely wrong when you copied the "backup". That is the reason one should check the backup after it had been created. Run `photorec` on the images. If the images are still there in those monstrous files it will extract the images and therefore reduce the file size. Besides that  this question is effectively more related to Windows and data recovery than Android (because Windows created that monstrous files and the original Android system does no longer exists).